# Android - Drag and Drop an copy of ImageView

Tags: android

How I can create a copy of ImageView on Drad and Drop? I searched in google, but i don't found nothing.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html) a full example that appears to do most of what you want to do. It appears the only change required is to create a new ImageView and copy the bitmap into it.To do that, you'd need to alter the onDrag() method of the class MyDragListener to be something like this:

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
    // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
    //ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent(); // Removed
    //owner.removeView(view);                         // Removed
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;

    // Added the following to copy the old view's bitmap to a new ImageView:
    ImageView oldView = (ImageView) view;
    ImageView newView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    newView.setImageBitmap(((BitmapDrawable) oldView.getDrawable()).getBitmap());

    container.addView(newView);                       // Changed to add new view instead

    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    break;
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: Sorry about that; I didn't actually try it and forgot about not being able to copy views directly. You'll need to create a new view and copy the original view's bitmap into it. I've edited my answer with the changes.

Comment: This time I built the example code from that site and tested my changes.

Answer (score 0):

How about dynamically creating an imageview when u click on a particular image. Then drag n drop the dynamically created image view